# Why will Data.append(_:) not take a rawValue of an enum of type Int in Swift for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, nsdata, foundation

```
import Foundation

enum Meridiem: Int {

    case anteMeridiem = 0
    case postMeridiem = 1

}

var data = Data()
data.append(10)
data.append(Meridiem.postMeridiem.rawValue)
```

In the previous code, I get an error in the last line saying:

```
Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Int)'
```

Yet I don't get an error when I append the literal 10. How would I append an enum into a variable of type Data?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. The definition of append takes the value of UInt8, so when I put the literal value of 10, it is automatically converted to UInt8, but when I put rawValue in, which is a variable of type Int, it is not automatically converted, so I need to convert it to UInt8 or change the type of the enum from Int to UInt8.

Comment: This is because `10` isn't a literal `Int`, it's an `IntegerLiteral`. In the absence of any type annotations, it will default to `Int`, otherwise it'll be able to initalize any [`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral) type, such as (in this example), `Int8`.